# Javascript works only once when function calls via button

Tags: javascript, django

I have a page with Javascript that calls a Django URL, but this call just work once.

The html code is here:

```
<script>
        function myFunction(pk) {
            if ($.data(this, 'submitted')){
                return false;
            }
            $.data(this, 'submitted', true);

            $.get("{%url 'myViewURL' %}",{req:pk}, function (data) {
                $.data(this, 'submitted', false);//libero

            });
        }</script>
```

Button code

```
<button onclick="myFunction({{id}});">Click Me</button>
```

The view code:

```
def myFuncView(request):
p_id=request.GET['req']
do_stuff(p_id)
return  redirect('anotherURL',p_id,permanent=True)
```

When is the first time I press the button, it fires, but after that it does not work anymore, even if I refresh the page or go to another page and come back!

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the `get` function refers to the ajax request, not the button which initiated it.

You need to store a reference to `this`, so you can then use it in a different context:

```
var self = this;
$.get("{%url 'myViewURL' %}", {
    req: pk
}, function (data) {
    $.data(self, 'submitted', false); //libero

});
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand you, but adding the `var self = this;` didn't solve anything. Did I miss something?

Comment: You must change the method - `$.data(this, 'submitted', false)` to use `self` instead of `this`.

Comment: that's not the problem, if I don't use this "submitted" flag, the error continues... `function myFunction(pk) { 

            $.get("{%url 'myViewURL' %}",{req:pk}, function (data) {

 
            });` this gives the error